# Update lock screen using a ScheduledTaskAgent

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to be able to update my lockscreen image using a scheduled task agent. I did look at [Building Windows Phone 8 Apps Development Jump Start](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/Content/ViewContent.aspx?et=2090&m=2076&ct=14365) which is a nice article.
My problem is in this video it's shown how to change your background with on picture from your isolated storage.
using :

```
  Uri imageUri = new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/shared/shellcontent/background2.png",                           UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

Which is not my case (I need to download it from a webservice).
I builded a small project with a piece of code which should download one image, store it to my isolated storage and then use it to upload my lock screen (I guess it's the best way to do what I want.).

To do so I used :

```
protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
{
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
      {
          SavePictureInIsolatedStorage(
              new Uri(
                  "http://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/101418789-cat-panleukopenia-fact-sheet-632x475.jpg"));
        
         // LockHelper();
          NotifyComplete();
      });

}
```

And :

```
private async void SavePictureInIsolatedStorage(Uri backgroundImageUri)
{

    BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
    await Task.Run(() =>
                       {
                        
                           var semaphore = new ManualResetEvent(false);
                           Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=>  
                                   {
                                       bmp = new BitmapImage(backgroundImageUri);
                                       semaphore.Set();
                                   });
                           semaphore.WaitOne();
                       });
    bmp.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
    WriteableBitmap wbmp = new WriteableBitmap(bmp);

    using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        var file = "shared/shellcontent/lockscreen.png";
        // when file exists, delete it
        if (myIsolatedStorage.FileExists(file))
        {
            myIsolatedStorage.DeleteFile(file);
        }

        using (var isoFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(file, FileMode.Create, myIsolatedStorage))
        {
            // use ToolStackPNGWriterExtensions
            ToolStackPNGWriterLib.PNGWriter.WritePNG(wbmp, isoFileStream);

        }

    }

}
```

My issue there is that my bitmap image does not seems to be downloaded.
I also tried with a WebClient by I am facing the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not awaiting your call, so `NotifyComplete()` will be called before anything has the chance to run. You can fix this by declaring your lambda function as `async`.

```
protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
{
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(async () =>
    {
      await SavePictureInIsolatedStorage(
          new Uri(
              "http://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/101418789-cat-panleukopenia-fact-sheet-632x475.jpg"));

      NotifyComplete();
     });
}
```

However watch that your method doesn't take too long to run as otherwise your scheduled task will not be scheduled again (after 2 failures of this kind).

Comment: Also, as a general rule, avoid `async void`; use `async Task` unless you're writing an event handler.

Comment: To be more specific, your lambda in BeginInvoke is async void. Read details in PFX Team Blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/08/10265476.aspx

Comment: @AlexSorokoletov - of course the lambda is async void, as I cannot modify the `BeginInvoke` API. The real issue is that the `SavePictureInIsolatedStorage` method in the OP's code is `async void`, whereas it should be `async Task`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx.